# When to use the pronoun en?

Tags: pronoms, prépositions

Which one is the correct sentence? If both are wrong, what is the correct way to say it?

> - La personne A peut transmettre alors que la personne B ne peut pas.
> - La personne A peut transmettre alors que la personne B n'en peut pas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pronouns are complicated, but there are some general rules (with exceptions) for third person pronouns:

- *de* + noun phrase → ***de lui/d'elle/d'eux/d'elles*** for a person; ***en*** for a thing.

  > Il parle de politique. → Il en parle.
  >   Elle parle de son père. → Il parle de lui.   *(or: Il en parle, referring to the topic (abstract concept) rather than the person — the meaning is the same.)*
  >   Je me passe de l'aide du stagiaire. → Je m'en passe.
  >   Je me passe du stagiaire. → Je me passe de lui.
  >   Le mur est couvert de lierre. → Il en est couvert.
  >   Je viens de Paris. → J'en viens.

  This goes not only when *de* is a preposition, but also when it's a partitive article leading a direct complement.

  > Veux-tu du gâteau ? → En veux-tu ?
  >   Je vois des étoiles. → J'en vois.

  When *de* introduces a noun complement (possessive or more generally genitive), the normal way to construct a pronoun is to use a possessive adjective. But *en* is also possible sometimes; it de-emphasizes the possessive aspect (see [What does « en » refer to in « en avoir la dignité »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23158/what-does-en-refer-to-in-en-avoir-la-dignit%C3%A9) on this topic).

  > Je vois la tête de Paul. → Je vois sa tête.   *(normal)*
  >     →   J'en vois la tête.   *(Can you see any part of Paul? Yes, I see his head peeking above the wall.)*
- *à* + noun phrase → ***lui/elle/leur/leur*** for a person; ***y*** for a thing.

  > Elle parle à ses enfants. → Elle leur parle.
  >   Je pense à mon travail. → J'y pense.
  >   Je vais à Paris. → J'y vais.
- other preposition + noun phrase → same preposition + *lui/elle/eux/elles*.

  > Elle vient avec ses amis. → Elle vient avec eux.
- no preposition → *le/la/les*.

  > Je promène mon chien. → Je le promène.

Here the pronoun refers to the action “*transmettre*”, and is a direct complement of the verb *peut*, so the pronoun would be *le*.

> La personne A peut transmettre alors que la personne B ne le peut pas.

But it would be more usual to omit the pronoun here (the sentence above is correct but awkward).

> La personne A peut transmettre alors que la personne B ne peut pas.

On the other hand *en* is not possible, because it would have to stand for “*<s>*la personne B ne peut pas de ???*</s>”.

Comment: To think: why can we say "La personne A peut transmettre alors que la personne B n'en est pas capable" ?

Comment: @Random Because “en” stands for “de transmettre”.

Comment: "EN serves to deemphasise the possessive aspect." Great! Merci.