# Negating participles and gerunds

Tags: négation, participe-présent

I am trying to ask how to negate participles and gerunds and will use examples that may or may not be idiomatic, as follows:

> (a) pouvant de patience
>
> (b) en pouvant
>
> (c) en pouvant de patience
>
> (d) en en pouvant

Example (a) is supposed to be a participial modifier meaning "capable of patience."

In (b), also a participial phrase, *de patience* has become *en*.

Example (c) is a gerund resulting from concatenating the preposition *en* and (a).

Example (d) is a gerund resulting from concatenating the preposition *en* and (b).

Again the examples may be unidiomatic or even ungrammatical (if so please let me know), but I hope it is clear what kind of examples I am trying to generate.

**Question**

How one should place *ne plus* in each of these?

For instance, (d) would give rise to these possibilities.

> n'en en pouvant plus
> en n'en pouvant plus
> en en ne pouvant plus

**Background**

As to being idiomatic, I am particularly doubtful of (d). *en en* may have a problem that *en la* or *en y* doesn't.

[This other question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17284/is-en-a-pronoun-or-preposition-in-n-en-pouvant-plus) of mine is somewhat related.  Thanks.

Comment: Where did you hear "pouvant de patience" ? It sounds ungrammatical to me. The closest sentence I see is "Je n'en peux plus d'impatience", meaning you can't wait anymore such you are impatient. Is this what you want to mean ?

Comment: @Random. I am sorry, but it was a made-up example. I just wanted (a) to be able to generate (b). But your "en n'en pouvant plus" actually answers all my questions. Namely, *ne* follows *en* as preposition, but precedes *en* as pronoun. So, if I see *en ne* I will know that this instance of *en* is a preposition, and if I see *n'en* I will know *en* is a pronoun. Would this be the correct lesson to draw?

Comment: It sounds good indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, capable of patience != pouvant de patience which means nothing.
In french, you'll find *posséder de la patience* or *avoir de la patience* or *être patient* or *prendre patience* or *faire preuve de sang froid*.
I think the last one is the best for your meaning of *capable of patience*.

These don't exist :
*n'en en pouvant plus*;
*en en ne pouvant plus*.
The one is gramatically correct, but never used. *en n'en pouvant plus*

In general gerund is unused in french. To place negation in your sentences, you'll have to place it on the previous verb. I couldn't find a way to use gerund on *faire preuve de sang froid*. Example : *The surgeon is operating with composure.* = *Le chirurgien opère en faisant preuve de sang froid*. To add negative : *The surgeon isn't operating with composure*. = *Le chirurgien n'opère pas en faisant preuve de sang froid*. To add negative with "plus" : *The surgeon isn't operating with composure since his accident.* = *Le chirurgien n'opère plus en faisant preuve de sang froid depuis son accident.*

For your information, "plus" is used for something what had been positive.

Comment: "en n'en pouvant plus" sounds correct, isn't it ? Same for "Le chirurgien opère en ne faisant pas preuve de sang froid"

Comment: @Random I can't find a sentence it would work. Give the one you have in mind please.

Comment: Let's say in a hot-dog contest: "Il a avalé le dernier hot-dog en n'en pouvant plus tellement son estomac était plein" maybe ? Even if you could say it another way.

Comment: @Julien Dryepondt 1. I am sorry that my examples were bad. I should have scoured the sources till I found well formed examples. 2. It is hard for me to believe that French speakers have no occasion to negate participial or *en* + participle phrases. "He sped on, not thinking of the child lagging behind." Wouldn't the French equivalent of this involve a negated participial or *en* + participle?

Comment: @Random I think it can work. But that sounds really weird. In french, the gerund/participe présent isn't really used. The sentence would be "Il a avalé le dernier hot-dog et n'en pouvait plus tellement son estomac était plein"

Comment: @Catomic "He sped on, not thinking of the child lagging behind." whould be translated by "Il filait sans penser à l'enfant en retard" The format to use the *participe présent* will be "Il filait en ne pensant pas à l'enfant en retard"
But the first one is more used, more natural.

Comment: @JulienDryepondt Indeed, that's what i meant by "Even if you could say it another way". It is not elegent, but you can do it, unlike what you say with "All of these don't exist". It should be "All of these are not elegent" :)

Comment: @Random I would have said "those are grammatically correct but are never used in french"

Comment: @JulienDryepondt Yeah :) But when reading your sentence a 2nd time, only the 2nd exemple is grammatical. The 1st and 3rd *does* not exist :)

Comment: @Random which are uncorrects?

Comment: @JulienDryepondt "n'en en pouvant plus" and "en en ne pouvant plus" are ungrammatical. "en n'en pouvant plus" is OK.

Comment: @Random Should i edit? ;)

Comment: @JulienDryepondt Oh yeaaahh ! :)

Comment: Thanks to you both. I've upvoted (but someone else has downvoted earlier) and accepted the answer.