# When to use "y" pronoun instead of other indirect object pronouns?

Tags: pronoms

I am practising French grammar rules when I came across **y** as an indirect pronoun. The author of the book uses it for almost all kinds of purposes. I have observed that **y**  closely translates to **it** and so I am inclined to think that maybe both **lui** and **y** can be used for instead of **it**.

Comment: See also [When to use the pronoun en?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/when-to-use-the-pronoun-en) which discusses *en* vs *y* vs *lui/elle/…*

Answer (score 7):

**y** et **en** sont deux **pronoms** particuliers, pour des formes **indirectes**, et qui portent sur des **choses, objets**, (en peut aussi porter sur une personne, plus rarement) :

**y = à cela**

> J'*y* pense = je pense *à cela*, *à cette chose*.

en anglais: *about it*

**y = à + lieu**

> J'*y* vais = je vais *à la plage*, *à l'hôpital*.

en anglais : *there*

**en = de cela**

> J'*en* parle = je parle *de cela*, *de cette chose*, *de cette histoire*.

en anglais : *about it*

*en* peut aussi porter sur une personne pour les verbes construits avec de, même si c'est plutôt sur une chose:

> J'en dépends = Je dépends de lui (correct et préférable).
>
> J'en parle = Je parle de lui (correct et préférable).

**lui** est le **pronom** **indirect** pour la troisième personne du singulier, pour une **personne** (en général):

> Je lui parle = je parle à lui, à cette personne, à mon frère (forme qui ne doit pas être employée)
>
> Je lui montre, Je lui donne.

en anglais : I give him ..., I show him ...