# How to translate “Le gratin <was mentioned>”?

Tags: grammaire, traduction

Basically, I am translating a recipe and I can't figure out how to say

> the gratin was mentioned

because it is an inanimate object, food.

- Do I say it is like *il*, and put *été* after it ?
- Or do I keep *être* in infinitive form and just say “*Le gratin être mentionner*”?

Also, further on there is a part that says *'the gratin was cooked'*, however the *'was mentioned'* will be phrased, I think that *'was cooked'* will be written the same way right?

Comment: It's a bad idea to ask about translations without providing context. But before you ask about translations, you should look up the words in a dictionary. I wonder why you want to use the infinitive form for *être*: it just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some rare exceptions, agreement depends only on the grammatical gender of a noun, and not on what it means. Since *gratin* is a masculine noun, the personal pronoun for referring to it is *il* if it's the subject of a verb. See [When to use the pronoun en?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/when-to-use-the-pronoun-en/16894#16894) for some of the cases where the personal pronoun isn't the subject (in some of those cases it does matter that it's an object rather than a person).

A literal translation of “the gratin was mentioned” is *le gratin a été mentionné* or *le gratin était mentionné*. The right tense depends on the context, there isn't a simple mapping between English tenses and French tenses. *<s>*Le gratin être mentionné*</s> is an ungrammatical jumble of words, just like *<s>gratin be mentioned</s> in English. It may well be the case that you shouldn't use the passive voice here in French, but that too depends on the context.

Cooked as opposed to raw is *cuit*. Once again, the context may matter.

Comment: Well in English it's kind of grammatical if it means “Le gratin soit mentionné” (but I doubt this is what the OP is looking for).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "le gratin" is inanimate does not affect the grammar in your case:

If you want to replace it with a pronoum, use **il** because it is a masculine word in French (**le** gratin).

"Was mentioned is a passive form in English, and so is it in French.

> Le gratin était mentionné...
>   Il était mentionné

is therefore correct. The same applies with "cooked" (translation depends on context, could be "cuit" or "cuisiné"