# What does « en » refer to in « en avoir la dignité »?

Tags: pronoms

> Tu ressembles peut-être à ton père, mais tu n’as pas l’air d’**en** avoir la dignité.
>
> = "You have the look of your father, sure, but you don’t exactly exude dignity, unlike him."
>
> = [you don’t have his dignity]

Am I correct in assuming that the sentence can be rephrased as:

> Tu ressembles peut-être à ton père, mais tu n’as pas l’air d’avoir la dignité **de {lui / ton père}**.

---

If so, can you also say something similar, such as:

> Tu ressembles peut-être à ta sœur jumelle, mais tu n’as pas l’air d’**en avoir la gentillesse**.
>
> or: Tu ressembles peut-être à ta sœur jumelle, mais tu n’**en** as pas **la gentillesse**.
>
> = "... but you don’t share your sister’s kindness"

Comment: But `Tu ressembles peut-être à ton père, mais tu n’as pas l’air d’avoir la dignité de lui.` is not correct. If you want to make it shorter : `Tu ressembles peut-être à ton père, mais tu n’as pas sa dignité.`.

Comment: Once again, as often when you say "Am I correct to assume...", you are correct ! :) **En** takes the place of the complement, here "*ton père*". IT avoids repetition. However I think you made a type in your second part : the second sentence is "*mais tu n'en a pas la gentillesse*". The verb "*avoir*" is there twice because of "*avoir l'air*", but if you don't use it there needs to be only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *en* refers to *ton père*. Generally speaking, the pronoun *en* stands for *de* + noun. See [When to use the pronoun en?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/when-to-use-the-pronoun-en/16894#16894) for a general introduction to pronouns and prepositions.

Here it would be possible to use either *sa* or *en*:

> Tu n’as pas la dignité de ton père.
>   Tu n’as pas sa dignité.
>   Tu n’en as pas la dignité.

The meaning is roughly the same, but there is a subtle distinction. Using *sa* suggests that the father's dignity may have been transmitted to the child, whereas using *en* merely suggests a similar dignity. However, this nuance is rather weak; it would perfectly possible to say “*sa dignité*” even if the people involved were not related and there was no suggestion that the quality was transmitted.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think "en" was generally allowed to be used to refer to a person, why is it allowed in this case?

Comment: Is the omission of « pas » in the third sentence intentional? If so, why?

Comment: @craig_h *En* can't be used for a person when it stands for a complement of a verb that's introduced by *de*. But when *en* stands for a complement of a **noun** that's introduced by *de* (which is a lot less common than the verb case), there is no person/object distinction.

Comment: Gilles, I don't understand your reply to @craig_h.  What's an example of the forbidden use?

Comment: @AntonSherwood See the answer I link to in my answer here. “Je me passe de l'aide du stagiaire.” → “Je m'en passe.” — “Je me passe du stagiaire.” → “Je me passe de lui.”