# Can "y" be used not just for locations?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, compléments

I know the *en* vs *y* question is frequently asked but I still don't get it at all...

I thought *en* would always be used to prevent repeating an "object" which represents a location.

Par exemple:

> Donnez-moi une suite au Ritz — je n'en veux pas.

And I thought *y* was always used for locations.

Par exemple:

> J'étais à Paris hier et je veux y aller demain encore une fois.

But now I've heard Indila singing in her song:

> Laissez-moi arriver, laissez-moi y croire....

And I cannot really figure out why is *y* used here instead of *en*.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: For a native French speaker (like me), laissez-moi y croire is the only correct form I can think of. I’m unable to really explain why since it’s so natural. On the other hand, the misusage of ‘y’ is real in some regions, specially in Lyon where it’s overused.

Comment: Does https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/when-to-use-the-pronoun-en answer your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pronoun *y* replaces a complement representing something inanimate introduced by *à*, or any kind of locative complement.

Like your example shows (*je crois à ça* : *j'y crois*), it is not limited to locations.

> Je réponds à la question : j'y réponds

Comment: To build this out a little more, we might say: *en* replaces any complement introduced with *de*, of any kind whatsoever. *y* replaces (a) some inanimate complements introduced by *à* and (b) location complements introduced by *à*, *en*, *dans* (if you can think of any others, all the better)

Comment: thanks for your answer! But "une suite au ritz" - c'est aussi un `à` mais ici elle a dit `je n'en veux pas`

Comment: *Je ne veux pas **d** 'une suite au Ritz !*

Comment: @LukeSawczak Any locative complement can be pronominalised by *y*, the preposition used doesn't matter much so long as it's not *de*. Je me suis assis sur le banc : je m'y suis assis, j'ai réservé une chambre hors de la ville : j'y ai réservé une chambre. Of course, other options are preferred to this locative *y* in spoken French, but in the formal language, it can and does refer to every kind of locative complement

Comment: @Eauquidort Good to know. That's what I started to write, and then checked myself: "Can I really generalize over *all* prepositions? Better just give a few I'm sure of..." :p

Comment: really? on dit `je ne veux pas d'une suite` et pas `je ne veux pas une suite?`? D'accord je vois...this leads me to my *real* question :D thanks a lot

Comment: Note that the dialog *Donnez-moi une suite au Ritz — je n'en veux pas.* doesn't make sense. That might be *Donnez-moi une suite au Ritz — Ils n'en ont pas de disponible.* (*en* = *une suite*) or *Donnez-moi une suite au Ritz — Il n'y en a pas de disponible* (*y* = *au Ritz*, *en* = *une suite*).

Comment: @jlliagre > It's not a dialog, that's the first sentence of the song "Je veux", by Zaz

Comment: @LaurentS. Doh, indeed. That's a rhetorical statement then, not a real question. This non-dialog makes sense then. Thanks!