# Can "y" be used to replace any location prepositional phrase?

Tags: pronoms

Before officially asking this question here, I looked it up here, and indeed found some corresponding answers. In this post:

[Can "y" be used not just for locations?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37296/can-y-be-used-not-just-for-locations)

*Eau qui dort* says:

> Any locative complement can be pronominalised by y, the preposition used doesn't matter much so long as it's not de. Je me suis assis sur le banc : je m'y suis assis, j'ai réservé une chambre hors de la ville : j'y ai réservé une chambre. Of course, other options are preferred to this locative y in spoken French, but in the formal language, it can and does refer to every kind of locative complement

I would like to check the accuracy of this answer. Can one replace any prepositional phrase that indicates location (regardless of which preposition is the head of the phrase) for **Y**?

Comment: I can't find any counter-example. Eau qui dort is certainly right (as he is always I guess). I just updated my reply to include that point.

Comment: There is an obvious exception: you can't use it for any construction that would require "en".

Comment: @Circeus - i.e: I can't use "y" when the preposition is "de", right?

Comment: @Circeus I guess that's what Eau qui dort excluded with "so long as it's not de":  *Je viens de Marseille* → *J'en viens*

Comment: Right, de takes en, à takes y, but y is not always *there*. Je pense aux examens=think about exams. j'y pense: think about them. No location here. I think that using these literal translations of French grammar in English is pretty confusing. "Any locative complement can be pronominalised by y". That means nothing to me.

Comment: @Lambie Eau qui dort didn't wrote *y* is always "there". Here is what the English sentence means: *Tout complément de lieu peut être pronominalisé en "y"*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not « location » that is concerned by « y ». It is the replacement for a « complément circonstanciel de lieu ».

How to find such a « complement » ? By answering the question « where does SUBJECT VERB? », aka « Où¹ dort-il ?  »
Answer: «  Il y dort. » or « Il dort dans un lit  ».
Here, « dans un lit » is the « complément circonstanciel de lieu ».

So, a « CCL » is everything that is postponed in such a complementary precision, at the end of the sentence, that you may replace by « Y » before the verb.

1: notice the accent on top of the U letter.

Comment: How is: Il y dort, not a place? He is sleeping there. Where is the subject carrying out the action described by the verb.

Comment: « there » is a location… even if it is, in my exemple, a COI :) Grammar is evil and I was wrong this time. However, it still applies… for most of the time… your comment about the exams is completely right!

Answer (score 2):

This is really a comment / query on Gaétan's answer, but unfortunately I don't have the rep to post comments.

Going back to the original example (very slightly modified) of *j'avais réservé une chambre hors de la ville*, I think you could go on to say *j'y passais presque tout mon temps*. In that sentence, I believe the *y* means *dans cette chambre*, and does not stand for the CCL *hors de la ville*. If, so, it seems that *y* does sometimes relate to a location that is not expressed by a CCL, even when the sentence also contains a CCL.

Comment: You are right completely :) Y is not necessary a replacement for a CCL, it can be a COI replacement too ; But… it is, in your exemple, a place, whatever the grammatical structure of the sentence object replaced.