# Does « y » always have to mean "there"? Could it replace other things referenced to by "à"?

Tags: pronoms, y

For the phrase:

> I love Madagascar! I make a toast to Madagascar!

The French equivalent might be something like:

> J'adore Madagascar ! Je lève un verre à Madagascar !

Ce sont deux questions:

Question: Est-ce qu'on peut dire, dans la dernière phrase:

> J'y lève un verre !

Question: Est-ce que cela pourra être compris comme:

> Je suis en Madagascar et je lève un verre ici.

Comment: À y penser, does this answer your question? [Can "y" be used to replace any location prepositional phrase?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42234/can-y-be-used-to-replace-any-location-prepositional-phrase)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, in standard French you couldn't say "*J'y lève un verre !*" for the last sentence, but yes "*J'y lève un verre !*" could be understood as "*Je lève un verre ici*" (though not very idiomatic).

In this sentence, *à* does not indicate location, it's a "[complément d'objet indirect](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_indirect)". Just like in English we don't say "*I make a toast **in** Madagascar*". Out of context it could be both, but if what you mean is "*I make a toast **to** Madagascar*" then *à* is not a location marker.

That means it wouldn't be replaced by "*y*". Following preposition rules, it would be:

> Je lui lève un verre !

But it's really not idiomatic. If you didn't want to repeat you'd say something like:

> J'adore Madagascar ! Je lève un verre en son honneur !

Note that you can also say:

> Je lui porte un toast !

Comment: What about "Je pense à toi. J'y pense."? In this example, y is not a location too, but it's acceptable. Why is that?

Comment: @jpmelos Good question. It's only used for things, abstract or real, not people, but your question still stands. You can say "Je pense à mon anniversaire. J'y pense.". I think you *could* say "Si je suis ici, c'est grâce à la révolution. J'y porte un toast !". It sounds weird, but it's probably grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

It can be used for indirect objects ("à" does not correspond to place but to an indirect object). Again according to *Le Bon Usage* "y" is not used as a second object, except in popular French, and at that, not in the whole country.

> (**LBU § 678**) *Y* s'emploie régulièrement comme objet indirect quand les pronoms conjoints objets indirects sont exclus […] :
> • *Elle s*'Y [= à un enfant] *était attachée* (E. et J. DE GONC., *Germ. Lacerteux*, VI).
> • *C'est un homme équivoque, ne vous* Y *fiez pas* (*Ac.* 1935).
> • *Certains écrivains, on prend plus de plaisir à* Y *songer qu'à les relire*
> (J. ROSTAND, *Pens. d'un biol*, p. 165).
> — Mais on peut dire avec la préposition et le pronom disjoint :
> • *Ne vous fiez pas* À LUI.
> — Les deux constructions se suivent dans cet ex. :
> • *Vous vous intéressez* À LUI ! *Je ne m*'Y *intéresse pas* (AUGIER, *Effrontés*, II, 10).
> Dans une grande partie de la France, ainsi qu'en Suisse et au Canada, le
> langage populaire emploie *y* comme objet second (= *lui*, plus rarement
> *leur*) à propos de personnes. Les écrivains font souvent parler ainsi leurs
> personnages du peuple :
> • *J*'Y [= pour sa femme] *achetai des bonnets, des
> robes* (MAUPASS., C., Fermier).
> • *Tu viens ? j'Y dis* [= lui dis-je]
> (GIONO, *Un de Baumugnes*, II).
> • *J'ai jamais compris qu'on pouvait apporter de l'encens à un enfant nouvellement-né pour* Y *faire un présent* (A. MAILLET, Sagouine, p. 69).
> —  Même intention chez PÉGUY :
> • *Elle se sauvait comme une pauvre vieille bonne femme toute seule. [...] On aurait eu envie d*'Y *prêter des enfants (Myst. de la char, de J. d'Arc*, p. 38)

The locution "lever un verre" does not mean literally "to lift up a glass", although when you do that you do lift a glass in your hand so as to drink its content. So "verre" is not analysable as a direct object, and it is impossible to refer technically to "Madagascar" as "object second"; however, it is perceived so and the construction does not have the feel of a usual standard construction.

Nevertheless "[y lève un verre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=y+l%C3%A8ve+un+verre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)" is not found. There is in Google Books only one case of "[y porte un toast](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22y%20porte%20un%20toast%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)" in which "y" is indirect object (similarly, "porter un toast can't be analysed as "verb and object").

[Gazette anecdotique, littéraire, artistique et bibliographique](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Gazette_anecdotique_litt%C3%A9raire_artistiq/3wc0AQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22y+porte+un+toast%22&pg=PA218&printsec=frontcover)  Que la loi de Darwin triomphe , J'y porte un toast ! Guernesey

"[y porter un toast](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22y%20porter%20un%20toast%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) can be found in a "Harlequin" and two or three other recent publications in a light literature.

[Saint-Valentin (Harlequin Roman Coup de Coeur)](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Saint_Valentin_Harlequin_Roman_Coup_de_C/hXXuUcaW65wC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22y+porter+un+toast%22&pg=PT43&printsec=frontcover) En toutcas, ça mérite d'y porter un toast. Qu'estce que vousavez déjà pris cesoir?

[Reine des Batailles: La Reine Faucon](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Reine_des_Batailles/OIarDgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22y+porter+un+toast%22&pg=PT282&printsec=frontcover) Je vais y porter un toast.

[Vincent, gentilhomme galant - tome 1 Le naïf liberin - Volume 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vincent_gentilhomme_galant_tome_1_Le_na/KBEPCcJAMnYC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22y+porter+un+toast%22&pg=PT397&printsec=frontcover) Enfin, quand il fut assez loin, il se retourna, et disparut en courant dans l'amoncellement des ruines. — La belle aventure! sourit le vicomte, et qui montre la vanité des choses! Que j'aimerais avoir du vin pour y porter un toast, ...

[Rebelle, Pion, Roi (De Couronnes et de Gloire, Tome n°4)](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rebelle_Pion_Roi_De_Couronnes_et_de_Gloi/UDT5DQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22y+porter+un+toast%22&pg=PT66&printsec=frontcover) “Le gens qui vous entourent sont des idiots”, déclara Lord West, levant son verre comme s'il proposait d'y porter un toast. “Ils le sont s'ils vous croient capable de vous rabaisser à me supplier comme ça”, convint Claudius qui,

As this construction is found only in a poem , and only in a few recent publications it is difficult to decide whether this usage is to be prescribed or not. I would abstain from using it and say "Je lève un verre à Madagascar !".

---

> J'adore Madagascar ! Je lève un verre à Madagascar !
>
> J'y lève un verre !
>
> Question: Est-ce que cela pourra être compris comme:

> Je suis en Madagascar et je lève un verre ici.

That can be said but you have to add an indirect object (à quelqu'un, à quelque chose).

- Je suis à Madagascar et j'y lève un verre à sa prospérité. (*for example*)

Answer (score 0):

The rule that has not failed me yet is simple:

```
y = à ça
```

So you can use "y" to replace any expression where you'd otherwise say "à ça".

For example, in this dialogue:

```
- Penses-tu à ton travail ?
- Oui, j'y pense.
```

Comment: But  *j'y vais* ≠ *je vais à ça*

Comment: J'y vais = je vais à ... (ça = name of the place of which we just spoke.)  E.g. Vas-tu au bureau ? Oui, j'y vais.

Comment: *J'y ai dit viens derrière le bois.* ;-)

Comment: Oui et non. _Y _s'emploie régulièrement comme objet indirect quand les pronoms conjoints objets indirects sont exclus  : Elle S'Y [= à un enfant] était attaché. //
Dans une grande partie de la France, ainsi qu'en Suisse et au Canada, le langage populaire emploie _y _comme objet second (= lui, plus rarement leur) à propos de personnes. Les écrivains font souvent parler ainsi leurs personnages du peuple : J'Y [= pour sa femme] achetai des bonnets, des robes (MAUPASS., C., Fermier).  _Le Bon Usage_ (Grevisse et Goosse)